# App mysteriously disappearing from phone

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-sdcard

So it seems like "preferExternal" is totally and completely broken at least for some percentage (maybe 3%) of the Android population.

After deploying an update for my app with **android:installLocation="preferExternal"**, some users have reported a few issues.

"Your app disappeared from my phone"

"Since your latest update, everytime I restart phone the app is removed from homepage"

So I tell them either to 1) Move the app to the phone (settings, apps, app name, move to phone) or if app is truly gone (which appears to be the case for some) 2) Unmount SD card, re-install app from Play Store (My Apps screen), Re-Mount SD Card.

Ok, so those are the workarounds.

**There are a few things I could use some guidance on**:

- Is this issue due to a certain Android OS level or just random?
- Is it a known Android bug?
- Will deploying yet another update with
  android:installLocation="auto", prevent these issues (and why)?

Please answer what you can. It's actually quite a horrifying issue since there could be many users I'm not aware of that have had my app mysteriously disappear from their phones. Yet Google still lists this as a valid option in their documentation.

Comment: In the latest release I changed auto to preferExternal. Result was issues as mentioned in your question, and a lot of removals on Galaxy SII and Galaxy S Advance. Other devices seem ok. All running Android 4.1.

Comment: Yeah, I think preferExternal is just plain broken due to the fact that phones often unmount their sd cards randomly which breaks all these apps. Strangely though it seems to have affected me (and you) more than others (I'm assuming) otherwise I'd think there would be more attention to it.